# How can I get the current "full" URL displayed in the Browser?

Tags: url, development

I'm not looking for the solution using SPContext & so. I tried it but I can't get URLs like:
 http://mypage.com/testblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1 ) 
 thanks george 
ps: I forgot to mention that this is about a MS Sharepoint 2010 Visual Webpart
    and I'm programming in C#

Comment: What is the context of your situation, are you in an ItemEventReceiver, WebPart, DataViewWebPart, etc?

Comment: Visual WebPart! and I'm looking for a solution in C#...

Answer (score 3):

this.[Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx).[Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx).[URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx) should give you the URL of the current HTTP request.

Comment: thank you so much! that's perfect & so simple! this.Page.Request.URL.AbsoluteUri works all the time & It's way less complicated than working with SPContext & stuff! cheers george

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.

Comment: FYI - This property can be used by all ASP.NET pages, not just SharePoint pages.

Answer (score 1):

For a C# solution you could use HttpRequest.Url, that may get you the full current URL, or otherwise get the Url property form SPContext.Current.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to get the path and display it.

$(document).ready(function() { 
    var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
});

Answer (score 0):

Lori's answer will work, but if you haven't already loaded jQuery to do something else then it's probably just a waste of overhead to load it just for this purpose.

You can grab it with straight JavaScript:

```
var theURL = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Thanx, but I forgot to mention that I'm looking for a solution in C#. JavaScript is nice but I dont want to use it because of ActiveScripting(could be disabled in some browsers)...